# Как перезагружать страницу на localhost python?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

(Конфигурация - localhost, и html - ки)

Задаю вопрос - у меня есть дискорд бот, и я хочу сделать для него ВеБ - ИнТеРфЕйС. Все я это делаю на чистом питоне, если не считать встроенные библиотеки (os, sys...) . Страницы надо как - то перезагружать. И вроде бы нашелся какой - то костыльный метод - анализировать txt и перезагружать страницу если у него будет любое определенное значение. Только назревает один вопрос -- как это сделать?
Не хочу показаться не шарящим ни в чем (хотя это так и есть). Заранее спасибо.

(

В качестве ответа рассчитываю на что то вроде этого - ответ на вопрос или то как можно сделать лучше и по другому (только без фреймворков, плиз))

Ну все, еще раз спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для перезагрузки страницы надо на js добавить функцию, которая будет переодически стучать в питон и спрашивать нужно ли перезагрузиться.